# How to pass Object as parameter to java script function on onClick

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, spring-mvc

My main goal:
When i click the link, a new window should be opened and display the content of entire log file in that window and the window should not have an address bar and navigation buttons (Back, Forward).

Is there any other approach that i can reach my goal?

Here is what i am trying to do, I am trying to call the java script method by passing the url of log file and thought of implementing the code to open new window

```
<table id="serverLogsStats" class="serverLogsView">
   <c:forEach var="log" items="${logsList}" varStatus="i" >
      <tr>
        <td>${log.name}</td>            
        <td><a href="#" onclick="openLog('${log}');">Open log</a></td>        
      </tr>
   </c:forEach>
</table>


<script>
function openLog (log) {
    var abc = log.name;
    alert(abc);    
}
</script>
```

When i pass an object 'log' to the openLog function, the value is passing as a String. I want the log to be passed as an object.

Here my output is coming as undefined.

If i put 'alert(log);' it is printing the address of the object

Comment: No, JSP is server side component. Javascript is client side. Also, how would javascript understand a Java object?

Comment: javasctipt is unable to pass as object, your better guess is failed.

Comment: Have you tried assigning the java object to a javascript object and looping through that in js?

Comment: Is there any other approach that i can do for this: My main goal is when i click the link, a new window should be opened and display the log file in that window.

Comment: You mean content of your log file?

Comment: you are correct, the content of the log file!

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
<table id="serverLogsStats" class="serverLogsView">
   <c:forEach var="log" items="${logsList}" varStatus="i" >
      <tr>
        <td>${log.name}</td>            
        <td><a href="#" onclick="openLog('${log.name}');">Open log</a></td>        
      </tr>
   </c:forEach>
</table>


<script>
function openLog(logName) {
    alert(logName);    
}
</script>
```

You can't use java objects and use them directly as JS object, you can only pass primitives.

For your use case, you could have an URL server side taking a log name as parameter and displaying it's content.

Comment: This is working, but i want to pass the path instead of name. When i pass the path the output string has no "/" in the path. For example if i pass "c:\abcd\edfg", then the java script method shows it as  "C: abcd edfg". It did not work for "C:\\abcd\\defg"

Comment: You need to escape, but having the path with "c:\" in your url is bad, really bad (what if someone change the url to display something sensitive)

Comment: You are correct, but i just gave an example here. That should not be the case in real time...